PoE safety circuit
I am wondering on what happens in a PoE circuit (not the data part) if, as a safety measure, I use a crowbar circuit between VDD and GND in case I need to "disconnect" the device because something bad happened.
if not how should I implement a way to cut off the PoE power coming into the device?
Are there other safety procedures when designing a PoE device?

Throwing a crowbar across a PoE supply sounds like a Bad Idea. Better to go open-circuit instead. There are many chips on the market for this sort of function -- look for "e-fuse" and "hot swap controller" type parts. And many switching regulators have an "enable" input -- you can use that to disconnect on a fault as well.

What VDD and what GND you mean, in which part of a PoE system? The PoE supply on cable is generally not ground referenced so currently I am assuming you do not mean shorting the wires of the CAT cable.
